# Function not defined error while using import

Tags: python, function, import, module, file-not-found

I created two files in python
**First one is
mym.py**

```
def hello():
    print("Hello everyone")
    return
def summ(x,y):
    total=x+y
    return total
```

**and next one is
abc.py**

```
import mym

hello()
x=summ(3,4)
print(x)
```

**And the error msg which I am getting is...both the files are in same working directory and there is no error of module not found...its giving error of function not defined.**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Nisha/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/abc.py", line 3, in <module>
    hello()
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Nisha/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/abc.py", line 3, in <module>
    x=summ(3,4)
NameError: name 'summ' is not defined
```

**What is the problem in function definition I am unable to trace...**

Comment: In this case, you need to prefix the name of the module on the function, so using `mym.summ`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `abc.py` needs to be changed to:

```
from mym import *

hello()
x=summ(3,4)
print(x)
```

Otherwise you cannot access the functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
    import mym
    mym.hello()
    x = mym.summ(3,4)
    print(x)
```